# Missing Parameter in Web Service

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, web-services, crystal-reports

I am currently working on an Webservice to retrieve a pdf Document from an Crystal Report. As lonmg as there are no parameter Values in the Report, the service works fine. As soon as I use parameters in a Query the Reports can't be shown anymore and I retrieve an error like 'missing parameter values'. But there is only one Parameter and I am pretty sure that I set the value of that parameter... 
Here is the Code where I change/ add the value:

```
// param is a string like 'parametername:value'
string index = param.Split(':')[0];
string value = param.Split(':')[1];
// repDoc is the current Report
repDoc.ParameterFields[index].CurrentValues.Clear();
repDoc.ParameterFields[index].CurrentValues.AddValue(value);
// now i create the PDF as an HTTPresponse
repDoc.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, response, false, "Report");
```

I really have no idea why it doesnt work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the mistake... 
I did a repDoc.refresh() before I created the Report.. seems like the Parameter Values are dropped that way... after removing the Refresh everything works fine :)

thx for the help!!!

Gushiken

Comment: Why do I have to wait 48h to accept my own answer? Hm... I will accept it later, but the problem is solved I guess^^

Comment: Because it is Stackoverflows rule that if a user submits his own answer the 48 hour wait is to validate and see if any other users took issue with that answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to debug if param is really set?

I am sure != I checked it